# i'm getting Unhandled Promise rejection: Template parse errors: ionic 3

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic3

i'm unable to resolve this `error`

> Unhandled Promise rejection: Template parse errors: Can't have
>   multiple template bindings on one element. Use only one attribute
>   named 'template' or prefixed with * ("

here is my `controller`

```
 resposeData:any;
 public showJobsInitally = false;

employerId = 4; // for testing

    this.authService.postData(this.employerId, "jobsPostedByEmployer").then((result)=>{
        this.resposeData = result;     


        console.log(this.resposeData);     


    }, (err) => {

    });
```

here is my template: `html`

```
<ion-card *ngIf="showJobsInitally" *ngFor="let jobs of resposeData?.postedJobs">   
  <ion-card-header>
    {{jobs?.company_name}}
  </ion-card-header>
  <ion-card-content>
    <p>{{jobs?.skills}}</p>
    <p>{{jobs?.package}}</p>
    <p>{{jobs?.location}}</p>
    <p>{{jobs?.industry}}</p>
    <p>{{jobs?.job_type}}</p>                           
  </ion-card-content>
</ion-card>
```

> my `authService` receiving data in this format

```
{"postedJobs":[{"company_name":"Egdhdf","skills":"jdfjfgjgfjfg","package":"jbfjnbgfjfg","location":"gfgghjjghghj","industry":"kghhjghj","job_type":"fjdjgjghhg","expired_or_not":null},{"company_name":"Enigma Brand Solutions","skills":"php,mysql,javascript","package":"3 lakhs","location":"bangalore","industry":"Software","job_type":"permanent","expired_or_not":null}]}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only one structural directive is allowed on one element.

```
<ng-container *ngIf="showJobsInitally">
  <ion-card  *ngFor="let jobs of resposeData?.postedJobs"></ion-card>
</ng-container>
```

Angular doesn't guarantee any order of attributes added to an element, therefore it would be unclear if you want `ngIf` or `ngFor` evaluated first.

By using the `<ng-container>` helper element, which is not added to the DOM, you can make that clear. `ngIf` and `ngFor` can be switched in my example code of course.